# How to change/rename value of kibana index field on kibana UI?

Tags: logstash, kibana, filebeat

I have set up an ELK stack on one server and filebeat on 2 other servers to send data directly to logstash.

Setup is working fine and I got log result as per need but when I see field sections on Kibana UI (Left side), I see "**host.hostname**" field which have two servers fqdns (i.e "***ip-113-331-116-35.us-east-1.compute.internal***", 
 "***ip-122-231-123-35.us-east-1.compute.internal***"
)

I want to set alias or rename those value as **Production-1** and **Production-2** respectively to show on kibana UI

How can I change those values without breaking anything

If you need any code snippet let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the field **host.hostname** is an ECS-field I would not suggest to rename this particular field.

In my opinion you have two choices:

1.) Create a pipeline in Logstash

You can set up a simple pipeline in Logstash where you use the mutate filter plugin and do a **add_field operation**. This will create a new field on your event with the value of host.hostname. Here's a quick example:

```
filter{
  if [host][hostname]{
    mutate{
      add_field => { "your_cool_field_name" => "%{[host][hostname]}" }
    }
  }
}
```

2.) Setup a custom mapping/index template

You can define field aliases within your custom mappings. I recommend reading [this article about field aliases](https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/introducing-field-aliases-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `translate` filter in the filter block of your logstash pipeline to rename the values.

```
filter {
    translate {
        field => "[host][hostname]"
        destination => "[host][hostname]"
        dictionary => {
            "ip-113-331-116-35.us-east-1.compute.internal" => "Production-1"
            "ip-122-231-123-35.us-east-1.compute.internal" => "Production-2"
        }
    }
}
```